# Googleapis outgoing connection

Tags: firefox, google, alert

I have little snitch installed on my mac. Recently I am getting an alert about an outgoing connection to **gcs-eu-00001.content-storage-upload.googleapis.com**. The IP address seems to belong to google. Is it safe for me to let it connect or should I deny it? By the way, I am using Firefox browser?

Comment: Do you have any Google apps (Chrome, Drive, Maps, etc.) *installed*? Even if you don't use them if you've run them once they've set up auto update and that's probably what that is, or if you use Google Drive it could be that updating. In the Little Snitch alert, if you hover over the section at the top, a Show Details button becomes available. Click that and it will give you more information. As to whether it's safe, it depends on how you feel about Google doing auto updates. I allow it, but others might disagree.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for replying. So that is related to Google trying to update its apps? Actually, I have none of Google apps installed... or none as far as I know and have intentionally installed. And I wonder what apps it is trying to update?

Comment: If you do the Show Details in Little Snitch it should give you more information (it will have the full path to the app making the request). It could also be things like a calendar program configured to use Google calendar, or something using Google docs, etc.

Comment: I get the following path: /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond

Comment: And also /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudKitDaemon.framework/Support/cloudd

Comment: I got curious, as in my case gcs-eu-00002.content-storage-download.googleapis.com was called from AssetChache. I can just be guessing purpose of this call. Blocked for now...

Comment: Few days ago Ive noticed googleapis.com being called from com.apple.Safari.SafeBrosing.Service - this was kind of obvious that its some kind of safe website list and it was called randomly while Safari was not open with any pages.

Comment: And yet again, now "mstreamd" service is calling gcs-eu-00002.content-storage-download.googleapis.com, its seams that everyone just want to reach this service now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some iCloud services, including iCloud Photos, appear to use these Google Cloud Storage hosts *(and apparently some AWS ones as well)* to augment Apple’s own server inventory:

- `gcs-*.content-storage-upload.googleapis.com`
- `gcs-*.content-storage-download.googleapis.com`
- This would likely be in an attempt to rapidly scale capacity and/or to decrease latency.

If those domains are blocked, iCloud photos should *(eventually)* realize that fact and fall back to AWS, Akamai, or Apple hostnames.

If your device is *not* signed into iCloud *(or Google, of course)*, further investigation would be warranted.

References:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7341139?answerId=29330065022#29330065022
- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/icloud-using-googleapis-for-download-upload.2277244/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/644sp5/iphone_hitting_upload_bandwidth_when_plugged_in/
- *(also, see comments on the question above)*